# How do I give Invoke-Command more time to run another script

Tags: powershell

Im trying to run a local script to run a server script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -Credential MyCredentials {Start-Process "C:\Program Files\test.new.cmd"}
```

So here comes the problem, it runs the Script, but not for long enough. It generates me only one file and the server script needs around 6 seconds to rule everything.

What I have to change to let it run for longer time?

Comment: If you add -Wait to Start-Process, that should block until the test.new.cmd is finished

Comment: @kah608 Oh it worked, cant believe it was that easy. Thank you!

Comment: @kah608, you should put that as an answer rather than just a comment. I would do it but i would feel bad about taking credit for it and getting the rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start-Process can wait for the command you are running by using the -Wait parameter. So you should use:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -Credential MyCredentials {Start-Process "C:\Program Files\test.new.cmd" -Wait }`